# Bash script for making Symlinks not working

Tags: git, bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to get a bash script for symlinking some git hooks to work, but having some trouble with it.

I currently have the .git/hooks folder and the git-hooks/hooks folder on the same level. The git-hooks/hooks folder, contain the hooks I want to symlink.

My current script is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CURRENT_PATH="`pwd`"

for hook in hooks/*;
    do
        temp=${hook}
        temp=${temp:6}

        ln -s "$CURRENT_PATH/${hook}"    "$CURRENT_PATH/../.git/hooks/${temp}"
    done
```

This script is on the same level has the /hooks folder.

But the only thing I get when trying to execute the script is

```
: No such file or directory
```

Any idea on what may be causing this?

Comment: Whats in the hooks directory? Guessing this has something to do with you not quoting your variables. Also no need for a subshell, there is already a variable `$PWD`.

Comment: The hooks directory has some git hooks. Those are supposed to be symlinked by the .git/hooks folder.

Comment: I meant what are the filenames?

Comment: https://github.com/DailyMatters/git-hooks this is the repo where I'm storing the hooks. The script code is also there.

Comment: K thanks. What output do you get if you replace `ln -s` with `echo`?

Comment: Still ": no such file or directory"

Comment: With the change on the shebang I stopped having the error, but the symlink is still not working. Now I will try to find out why. Thanks.